# "FailingHttpStatusCodeException: Too much redirect for" - HtmlUnit Will Not Load

Tags: java, htmlunit

So I'm trying to load a page with HtmlUnit in Java and I am getting this error:

"FailingHttpStatusCodeException: Too much redirect for *website*"

Does anyone have advice on how to fix this? I've been stuck on this for a while.

There's heavy JavaScript on the page, it is a Steam Trade page if that helps at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work by using .getPage().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();